# Change Value of Nested Object - MongoDB Java

Tags: java, mongodb, object, nested, mongodb-query

I'm making a MongoDB statistic system using the Java driver, and I am wondering if it is possible (and how) to change the value of a key nested inside many objects. Here is how my database is formatted:

```
{
  location : “chicago”,
  stats : [
    {
      "employee" : "rob",
      "stat1" : 1,
      "stat2" : 3,
      "stat3" : 2
    },
    {
      "employee" : "krista",
      "stat1" : 1,
      "stat2" : 3,
      "stat3" : 2
    }
  ]
}
```

So, for example, how could I change Rob's "stat2" to another value? I am new to JSON and the MongoDB Java driver. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the [positional `$`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) operator and [$set](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) in order to update what you want.

```js
db.collection.update(
    { _id: <docId>, "stats.employee": "rob" }, 
    { "$set": { "stats.$.stat2": <value> } }
)
```

So you match your document and the required element of the array. The update side uses that array index to know in which element to update. The [$set](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) operator only updates the specified field.

In Java, Build with BasicDBObject.

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("_id", id);
query.append( new BasicDBObject("stats.employee", "rob") );

BasicDBObject update = new BasicDBObject("$set",
    new BasicDBObject("stats.$.stat2", value));

collection.update(query,update);
```